# Getting a NSString from NSMutableArray - Unexpected value from objectAtIndex:0 Issue - PhoneGap/ Cordova project

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I'm a total noob to `Objective-C` and I'm having an issue with getting the correct value from a `NSMutableArray` that contains `NSStrings`.

I am making an `iOS PhoneGap` project, that needs to use the clipboard. Having hacked an old iOS phonegap clipboard plugin, that from my javascript calls:

```
 cordova.exec(successFunction, failureFunction, "ClipboardPlugin", "setText", ["This is what it should be"]);
```

Where:

`successFunction` = success callback,

`failureFunction` = failure callback,

"`ClipboardPlugin`" = name of the class that has holds the native plug in code

"`setText`" = name of the class method called that sets the clipboard text,

["This is what it should be"] = single entry to an array of arguments, that is passed to the `Clipboard.setText` method.

When the `setText` method is called and I step through it in the debugger, it is called correctly and the correct parameters are in the array (that is, one object, value= "This is what it should be"), but when I try to access it using `objectAtIndex:0`, it returns something unexpected.

Code:

```
 @implementation ClipboardPlugin


 -(void)setText:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options{

      /* At this point: NSMutableArray* arguments = 2 objects:
      [0] 0x432432f0 @"This is what it should be"
      [1] 0x00000000

       - so far... so good!

      */

      UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
      NSString     *text       = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

      [pasteboard setValue:text forPasteboardType:@"public.text"];

    /* At this point: 
         NSString* text = ??? "What it should be" - ?? WRONG!
                   text = "@ClipboardPlugin1212332348"

      */

 }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you manage to store `nil` at index 1 in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [array lastObject]; 
or try adding the @ to the array